# Code is getting executed even when hitting cancel button (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay so I have a function "deactivate" which passes in 3 parameters to it.

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="deactivate('{{ $user->getRoleName() }}', '{{ $user->getFullName() }}', {{ $user->id }}); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small delete">
<i class="btn-icon-only"></i>
Deactivate User
</a>
```

Here is my function:

```
function deactivate(title, name, id) {
    $('#modal-user-role').html(title);
    $('#modal-user').html(name);
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: '/user/' + id + '/',
          type: 'PUT',
          success: function (data) {
             $('#alerts').html('<p class="alert alert-success">Successfully deactivated ' + title + ': ' + name + '</p>' + $('#alerts').html());
             $('#r' + id).hide();
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             $('#alerts').html('<p class="alert alert-error">A problem occured while deactivating ' + title + ': ' + name + '</p>' + $('#alerts').html());
             $('#r' + id).hide();
          }
       });
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML that goes with the function:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close icon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Deactivate User</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to deactivate user <span id="modal-user-role"></span>: <span id="modal-user"></span>?</p>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button id="confirm" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm Deactivation</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why my cancel button is not working? I believe it has something to do with the onclick I am using but not quite sure how to fix it.

So, basically if I click the deactivate user button and than cancel and click another user and then cancel and then click another user and than confirm the deactivation it will delete each user from the DB. 
Which I do not want.

I have the button type="button" which I thought would fix it. But it is not.

Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simply giving an ID to your "Cancel" button?

Comment: and do what with that ID? just give an ID thats it?

Comment: Yep, just give it an `id="cancelButton"` or something :)

Comment: added this to the cancel button:

<button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>

Did not work.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v80b6o1a/2/

Comment: but there is another bug in the code... in the attached fiddle click on `Deactivate User` then on `Deactivate User 2`, you can find that `Deactivate User` is called twice(need to click on confirm in both cases)

Comment: Are you removing the event handler from `confirm`?  Because the event handlers are additive.  Each time you are calling `deactivate()` you are adding a new event handler.  Actually that will be your problem.  Remove the event handler before assigning the new one.

Comment: Yes the pops etc... work fine but the problem is coming that the cancel button is not functioning. If you hit cancel yes it exits the popup but it still saves the PUT request. and than if you hit confirm later on it will still deactivate the user you hit cancel on...

Comment: Jane do you have an example of that?

Comment: That's consistent with not removing the handler.  When you finally click `confirm`, all three event handlers are firing with the value of `id` from previous assignments of the handler.

Comment: if you look at the attached fiddle the confirm click handle is not called when the cancel button is clicked... but the problem is consistent with the issue I described earlier

Comment: Call unbind - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/  `$( "#confirm").unbind( "click" );`  then call your current binding function on the next line.

Comment: It gets called in my code :/

Comment: can you confirm the case... you are getting the confirm message then cancelling it again you are trying with another user at that time both are getting deactivated

Comment: one easy thing you can try is to use `.off()` like `$('#confirm').off('click.deactivate').on('click.deactivate', function () {...});`

Comment: then see my comment above using `.off()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v80b6o1a/3/

Comment: I can't quite see what you're asking me to confirm, but just add the line of code I put before directly before your `$('#confirm').click(function() {...`

Comment: AWESOME! that worked Arun! Ugh sooo simple! I believe that was inline with Jane's suggestion also same idea atleast. I think both would work. Just happened to try Arun's first.

Comment: Arun, can you explain to me why that fixes it? is it because the next time you click on a different user lets say it will will turn off the click previously with the .off?

Comment: when you click the first time, 1 handler is added that you cancel... but still the registered handler is present... then when you try to de activate the second user a second handler is added... now when you click on confirm both first and second handlers are bound to the button so both gets executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the problem is how you are registering the click handler...

since the click handler is registered within the `deactivate` method, every time the method is called a new handler is added - it doesn't remove the previously added handlers...

so you can try to remove the handlers using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$('#confirm').off('click.deactivate').on('click.deactivate', function () {
})
```

Note: When using event unbinding I prefer using [name spacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)